# Is it a good idea (maintainability) that making a generic class <T=number[]> is related but different to any property/constructor argument's type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm making a TypeScript library and the class is like:

```js
class Data {
    // The library user will treat internalData as multiDimensionArray according
    numberOfdimension: number; 
    internalData: any 
    constructor(
      numberOfdimension: number 
      //..
    );
}
```

If a user pass `numberOfdimension` as 1, it is equivalent that the user will treat Data as `number[]` via its API, if `numberOfdimension` is 2, it will be like `number[][]`. So it might be good to note this instance as `Data<number[]>` and `Data<number[][]>` respectively. However, due to the limitation that the number value of `numberOfdimension` cannot automatically reflect the `Data<T>`, is it good that let users can manually assign the generic type and `numberOfdimension`? So they can quickly know the current code is using `Data<number[]>` or `Data<number[][]>` or higher and IDE can have the intelligence on the instance. I think the drawback is the `numberOfdimension` needs to be synchronized with passing generic.

Is this a good idea?

```js
class Data<T=number[]> {
    // The library user will treat internalData as multiDimensionArray according
    numberOfdimension: number; 
    internalData: any
    constructor(
      numberOfdimension: number 
      //..
    );
}
 
const data1 = new Data<number[]>(1);
const data2 = new Data<number[][]>(2);
calculation(data1, data2);
function calculation(input1: Data<number[], input2: Data<number[]){
    // ..
}
```

Comment: If there is always either `numberOfdimension = 1` or `numberOfdimension = 2`, then have 2 separate structures

Comment: No, it can be 3, 4, 5 or more dimension, respectively number[][][], number[][][][], number[][][][][].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have generic util for calculating level of nested arrays:

```js
type Dimension<N extends number, Default = number, Level extends number[] = [],> =
  Level['length'] extends N
  ? Default
  : Dimension<N, Default[], [...Level, 1]>

type Test1 = Dimension<1> // number[]
type Test2 = Dimension<2> // number[][]
type Test15 = Dimension<15> // number[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NrGQam)

There is no need to provide explicit type during calling `new Data`.
Whole solution:

```js
type Dimension<N extends number, Default = number, Level extends number[] = [],> =
  Level['length'] extends N
  ? Default
  : Dimension<N, Default[], [...Level, 1]>

type Test1 = Dimension<1> // number[]
type Test2 = Dimension<2> // number[][]
type Test15 = Dimension<15> // number[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

class Data<T extends number>{
  constructor(count: T) { }
  handle = (list: Dimension<T>) => {

  }
}

const result = new Data(2)
result.handle() // expected number[][]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9pO8w)

`Dimension` - recursively call itself if `Level['length']` is less than provided number `N`. Once length of `Level` equals `N` - it returns `Default`. As you might have noticed, every time `Level` length is increased by one.